# How to fix this simple ElementNotFoundException in Blazor?

Tags: c#, nunit, blazor, blazor-webassembly, bunit

I am unit testing a blazor app. I get a ElementNotFoundException. I think the cause for this is an if statement in the the index.razor page. see code below:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        @if ((challenges != null) && (challenges.Count > 0))
        {
            <MultiStepComponent Id="MultiStepContainer" Challenges="@challenges">
                <div class="row p-3">
                    <div class="col-6" id="challengeContainer">
                        @foreach(var c in challenges)
                        {
                            <MultiStepNavigation Name="@c.Title">
                                <h1>@c.Title</h1>
                                <img class="float-left" src="@c.ImagePath" width="200" />
                                @foreach(var sentence in c.Description)
                                {
                                    <p>@sentence</p>
                                }
                            </MultiStepNavigation>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <textarea rows="26" cols="120" @bind="input" id="input"></textarea>

                        <button class="btn" id="runBtn" @onclick="RunAsync">Run</button>

                        <br />
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="120" id="output" readonly>@((MarkupString)Output)</textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </MultiStepComponent>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

The code behind of this page (index.razor.cs) has the following initialization code:

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        jsonRepository = new JSONChallengeRepository();
        challenges = await jsonRepository.GetChallengesAsync();
    }
```

The test for this page is here:

```
[Test]
    public async Task Compile_code_Success()
    {
        _codingChallengeService.Setup(c => c.SendInputToCompilerAsync("50+50")).ReturnsAsync("100");
        _testContext.Services.AddScoped(x => _codingChallengeService.Object);
        var razorComponent = _testContext.RenderComponent<Index>();
        razorComponent.Instance.challenges = GetChallenges();

        if ((razorComponent.Instance.challenges != null) && (razorComponent.Instance.challenges.Count > 0))
        {
            var runBtn = razorComponent.FindAll("button").FirstOrDefault(b => b.OuterHtml.Contains("Run"));
            var input = razorComponent.Find("#input");
            input.Change("50+50");
        
            runBtn.Click();
        
            var outputArea = razorComponent.Find("#output");
            var outputAreaText = outputArea.TextContent;
            Assert.AreEqual("100", outputAreaText);
        }

        Assert.IsNotNull(razorComponent.Instance.challenges);
    }
```

The #input is missing..Why??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is Bunit I suspect razorComponent.Find("#input") isn't looking for a component with an id of "input".  Try razorComponent.Find("textarea")

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the problem is that you do not cause the component under test to re-render when you assign `razorComponent.Instance.challenges` property/field, and if the component does not re-render, then the markup inside `@if ((challenges != null) && (challenges.Count > 0))` block in the component is not displayed.

In general, dont mutate properties (parameters) of components through the `razorComponent.Instance`. If you really have to do so, make sure to [trigger a render](https://bunit.dev/docs/interaction/trigger-renders.html) after.

Instead, [pass parameters to the component](https://bunit.dev/docs/providing-input/passing-parameters-to-components.html) through the `RenderComponent` or [SetParametersAndRender](https://bunit.dev/docs/interaction/trigger-renders.html#setparametersandrender) methods, or through [services injected](https://bunit.dev/docs/providing-input/inject-services-into-components.html) into components. That will cause the component to go through its normal render life-cycle methods.